# Get the listItem ID in a onClick method of SetOnClickListener method of an adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an activity which lists objects from an array objects through a custom adapter. The row of this adapter contains several EditText's and a layout which is clickable and does the deleting of that object selected. My intention is the object can be updated by clicking on the item (which shows another activity) and deleting by clicking on the layout. So that, I have to implement the updating and the deleting by differents setOnItemClickListener's.

I have done the updating just setting an setOnItemClickListener to the listView of objects and sending the whole object to a new activity through putExtra and getIntent.

The problem is with the deleting. I have implemented an OnClickListener directly on the adapter, like this:

```
holder.layoutEliminar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //Here call to an Async Task to delete the object but, what about t the id object???
     }
```

That code goes fine when I click on the layout of the row but I don't know the way to obtain the id of the object selected in the listView. Does anybody know how??

Do not hesitate to ask me for more code or details.
Please excuse my English, not native.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag for the view on your `getView`:

```
holder.layoutEliminar.setTag(theIdOfYourObject);
```

Note that `View.setTag(Object tag)` takes an `Object` as parameter ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))). I will assume that you want to set the id of the object to delete as `String` for the tag.

And then, on your `onClick`

```
holder.layoutEliminar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout layoutEliminar;

        // Retrieve your layoutEliminar from v
        // ...

        // Get the id of the object to delete from the tag
        String id = (String) layoutEliminar.getTag();
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello Antonio. Firstly thanks for your reply and apologizes about my delay in answering. I have been trying to implement your answer, but though I did my best, I was not able. What you mean with 'theIdOfYourObject' in the instruction holder.layoutEliminar.setTag(theIdOfYourObject);  That's my problem, I don't know how to send de Id of my object from the listView to the adapter. I'd really appreciate you to be more specific. Thanks again for you help!! Of course, I can send you the code if that may help you!

Comment: @Paco Ríos In your question you ask _what about t the id object???_. Well, with `theIdOfYourObject` I mean that you can set the ID that you need to identify your object (and then delete it). Take into account that `setTag` receives an `Object`as the parameter, so you can also set the object you want to delete as the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I already did with the help of @Antonio. I didn't use Tag's, I have used the instruction getItem(position).getId() into the method onClick to refer the id of the object (don't know if it's the best and more efficient way to do). Like this:

```
holder.btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("PedidosAdapter dd: ",String.valueOf(getItem(position).getId()));
            //Async Task for deleting the object with that ID
    }   
});
```